# Android | Kotlin : Return type of 'onCreateDialog' is not a subtype of the return type of the overridden member

Tags: android, kotlin

I am stuck with this error

> Return type of 'onCreateDialog' is not a subtype of the return type of
> the overridden member 'protected/*protected and package*/ open fun
> onCreateDialog(p0: Int): Dialog! defined in
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity'

I've just migrated my project from java to kotlin and now I am facing this kind of error and it is new to me, so any help will be much appreciated.

Code:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(id: Int): () -> ProgressDialog? {
        return when (id) {
            progress_bar_type -> ({
                pDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
                pDialog!!.setMessage("Sending Application. Please wait...")
                pDialog!!.isIndeterminate = false
                pDialog!!.max = 100
                pDialog!!.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER)
                pDialog!!.setCancelable(true)
                pDialog!!.show()
                pDialog
            })!!
            else -> null
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the whole class? can't see why you are overriding `onCreateDialog` :)

Comment: It defined as `fun onCreateDialog(id: Int): Dialog` just remove the method type it agin with suggestion . Also `onCreateDialog` is deprecated i guess .

Comment: Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821306/progressdialog-created-from-oncreatedialog-stops-animating-on-second-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreateDialog` is deprecated. The best solution for you would be to make a new class that extends DialogFragment (like `MyProgressDialog : DialogFragment`)

Then in `MyProgressDialog`, simply override `onCreateDialog`

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Dialog {
    val dialog = ProgressDialog(getActivity())
    // setup whatever you need
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.title_dialog);

    return dialog;
}
```

Then you simply create an instance and call `show` :

`MyProgressDialog().show(supportFragmentManager, "SomeTag")`